# Is it possible to get Boto3 | python output in tabular format

Tags: json, python-2.7, boto3, aws-cli, prettytable

in `aws cli` we can set output format as `json` or `table`. Now I can get json output from `json.dumps` is there anyway could achieve output in table format? 
I tried `pretty table` but no success

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please provide more information about what you are trying to accomplish? What do you mean by "tabular format"? Typically, the output is one-to-many that doesn't fit into a normal spreadsheet-like view.

Answer (score 2):

Python Boto3 does not return the data in the tabular format. You will need to parse the data and use another python lib to output the data in the tabular format . Pretty table works good for me, read the pretty table lib docs and debug your code.